# How to unpivot this table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables, unpivot

I have created a temp table that I would like to unpivot it, but I keep getting an error message as follow:
   **Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 196
   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.**

My temp table is below:

Dossier Order Number  T_Code  Routine_Labour  Variable_Labour

[image]

I would like to unpivot it to below:

[image]

I used the script below:

```
Select 
Dossier,
Order_Number,
T_Code,
Labour_Type,
Amount

from 
#LabourSplit

Unpivot 
(
 Amount for Labour_Type in (Routine_Labour, Variable_Labour)
 ) as LabourSplit_U
```

As soon as I run this script, the error message pop up. even I commented out the two columns in the temp table and in the script, the error message is still there.

```
Select 
Dossier,
--Order_Number,
--T_Code,
Labour_Type,
Amount

from 
#LabourSplit

Unpivot 
(
 Amount for Labour_Type in (Routine_Labour, Variable_Labour)
 ) as LabourSplit_U
```

Comment: can you just copy paste those rows instead of putting them as images ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? And what is the compatibility level of the database you are connecting to?

Comment: @MartinSmith That is SQL Server 2012.Not sure about the compatibility level of the database. I think it might be to do with the version. Coz even I run the online example the same error appears. http://www.ingenioussql.com/2013/05/09/standard-t-sql-unpivot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
Dossier,
Order_Number,
T_Code,
Labour_Type,
Amount
FROM
(
  Select 
  Dossier,
  Order_Number,
  T_Code,
  Routine_Labour, 
  Variable_Labour
  from #LabourSplit
) a
Unpivot 
(
  Amount for Labour_Type in (Routine_Labour, Variable_Labour)
) as LabourSplit_U
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/294e4/1)

Results:

```
| DOSSIER | ORDER_NUMBER | T_CODE |     LABOUR_TYPE | AMOUNT |
|---------|--------------|--------|-----------------|--------|
|    1234 |         5678 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     10 |
|    1234 |         5678 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     20 |
|    1234 |         3434 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     20 |
|    1234 |         3434 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     70 |
|    1234 |         5671 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     30 |
|    1234 |         5671 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     10 |
|    1234 |         3422 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     40 |
|    1234 |         3422 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     40 |
|    1234 |         1122 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     11 |
|    1234 |         1122 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     30 |
```

However, UNPIVOT as far as I know is supported in full versions of SQL Server. If you have a compact edition or other free versions you need to use `UNION ALL`:

```
Select 
Dossier,
Order_Number,
T_Code,
'Routine_Labour' AS Labour_Type,
Routine_Labour AS Amount
FROM LabourSplit
UNION ALL 
Select 
Dossier,
Order_Number,
T_Code,
'Variable_Labour' AS Labour_Type,
Variable_Labour AS Amount
FROM LabourSplit
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/294e4/3)

Results:

```
| DOSSIER | ORDER_NUMBER | T_CODE |     LABOUR_TYPE | AMOUNT |
|---------|--------------|--------|-----------------|--------|
|    1234 |         1122 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     11 |
|    1234 |         1122 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     30 |
|    1234 |         3422 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     40 |
|    1234 |         3422 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     40 |
|    1234 |         3434 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     20 |
|    1234 |         3434 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     70 |
|    1234 |         5671 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     10 |
|    1234 |         5671 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     30 |
|    1234 |         5678 |      1 |  Routine_Labour |     10 |
|    1234 |         5678 |      1 | Variable_Labour |     20 |
```

Comment: It is either not SQL Server 2008, or your data type for Routine_Labour and Variable_Labour is different. Check the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/294e4/1

Comment: Great Thanks. Mine is SQL Server 2012. So what can I do with 2012 version?

Comment: Here is the fiddle for SQL Server 2012. Works there as well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/294e4/1

Comment: Unless, your SQL Server is a "compact edition", or some other off-cuts of the full version

Comment: stay with me, I'll give you another solution that will work there

Answer (score 2):

I think CROSS APPLY VALUES is easier to use and understand than UNPIVOT

```
SELECT Dossier
      ,Order_Number
      ,T_Code
      ,Labour_Type
      ,Amount
FROM #LabourSplit
     CROSS APLLY (
         VALUES (Routine_Labour, 'Routine_Labour')
               ,(Variable_Labour, 'Variable_Labour')
     ) AS CA1(Amount, Labour_Type)
```